# Set visibility for view to gone for an inflated layout

Tags: android, visibility, layout-inflater

I am trying to set the visibility of some views as gone after layout inflation but it doesn't work. If I try to access the tag of the view , I can clearly see that I am accessing the right view. This code doesn't result to any errors, so I am trying to understand why it's not working.

I am passing in as parameters the resource ids for the views (hideView) and the layout(layout):

```
public void hideViews(String title, ArrayList<Integer> hideView, int layout){

    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    final View originalView = factory.inflate(layout, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < hideView.size(); i++) {

        View view = originalView.findViewById(hideView.get(i));

        if (title.equals("Admin") || title.equals("Manager")){
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, share your view's `.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

`originalView` is not attached to your layout.

1. Either provide the parent view where you want to inflate this layout
2. Or add `originalView` as a child of other attached view after inflating.

Let's assume that this is your parent view

```
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.parentView);
```

**Solution 1**

**Replace this:**

```
final View originalView = factory.inflate(layout, null);
```

**With:**

```
final View originalView = factory.inflate(layout, parentView);
```

**Solution 2**

**Add this:**

```
parentView.add(originalView)
```